# How to modify apalike.bst to remove period(.) after "author (year)"?

Tags: bibtex

which part of apalike.bst do I have to change to remove the period . after "author (year)" ?

Instead of "author (year)." I need "author (year)"

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Should the change in format apply to all entry types (`@article`, `@book`, etc) or only to certain entry types?

Comment: Yes, the change in format should apply to all entry types (@article, @book, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that avoids the problem identified in my comments on @Qwerty's own answer.

Begin by making a copy of the file `apalike.bst`; call the copy, say, `myapalike.bst`. In `myapalike.bst`, find the the function `output.year.check`. Replace the entire function with the following code:

```
FUNCTION {output.year.check}
{ year empty$
  { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
  { write$
      " (" year * extra.label * ")\removeperiod" *    
  mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }  
if$
}
```

Note that there's now no space between `")` and `\removeperiod"`.

Save the file `myapalike.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, you will likely also need to update the filename database of your TeX distribution. And, change the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` instruction from `apalike` to `myapalike`.

Separately, provide the following code in the preamble of your document:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removeperiod}{\@ifnextchar.{\@gobble}\relax}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the `apalike.bst` file and paste it where the required .tex and .bib files are located. Rename  it, (say) `myapalike.bst`. 
For editing, open the `myapalike.bst` using some text editor (I used notepad). 
Search for `FUNCTION {output.year.check}.`
Now modify it as follows:

```
FUNCTION {output.year.check}
{ year empty$
  { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
  { write$
      " (" year * extra.label * ") \removeperiod" *    
  mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }  
if$
}
```

Also add the following code in your document preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removeperiod}{\@ifnextchar.{\@gobble}\relax}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I'm afraid this solution isn't quite right. It indeed deletes the "." character, but in the process it inserts too much whitespace between the closing parenthesis of the `year` field and the first word of the `title` field. As a result, there's a noticeable difference between the whitespace between the `year` and `title` fields and the other interword whitespaces. In short, you also need to remove the space that LaTeX inserts immediately ahead of `\removeperiod`. Hint: Modify the definition of `\removeperiod` by inserting the instruction `\unskip` immediately before `\@ifnextchar.`.

Comment: Or, maybe more simply, change one of the modified lines in `myapalike.bst` to `" (" year * extra.label * ")\removeperiod" *`, i.e., don't insert a space between `)` and `\removeperiod` that then has to be `\unskip`-ped.