# First Name First After First Author in apalike

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, apa-style

I use `apalike` modified to show [first names in references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275402). This version works well, but I want to locate first names first for all authors after the first one. For example, I want to have `Doe, John and Jane Doe` rather than `Doe, John and Doe, Jane` in references. Can I change `apalike`'s naming order for second and third authors? Here's the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\cite{asdf}
\bibliography{asdf}
\end{document}
```

And `asdf.bib` contains the following information.

```
@article{asdf,
    title={asdf},
    author={Doe, John and Doe, Jane},
    journal={asdf},
    volume={1},
    number={1},
    pages={1--2},
    year={1111}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant function to be changed in your modified `.bst` file is the function

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
```

which is on line 209 of the original `.bst` file.  In your modified version of the you may have the following formatting schema which says put the full first name first last.

```
s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}" format.name$ 't :=   % last name first
```

Change this to:

```
s nameptr 
    duplicate$ #1 > 
        { "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" }
        { "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}" }
    if$
    format.name$ 't :=   % last name first
```

which will put full first name first on all non-initial names.

As with any modification to a `.bst` file, make sure you rename it and work on a copy of the original (which I assume from your question you are already doing.)

Here's a sample document with the changed `.bst` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{BerwickPietroskiYankama2011,
    Author = {Robert Berwick and Paul Pietroski and Beracah Yankama and Noam Chomsky},
    Journal = {Cognitive Science},
    Pages = {1207-1242},
    Title = {Poverty of the stimulus revisited},
    Volume = {35},
    Year = {2011}}

@article{Chomsky1977,
    Author = {Noam Chomsky and Howard Lasnik},
    Journal = {Linguistic Inquiry},
    Pages = {425-504},
    Title = {Filters and Control},
    Volume = {8},
    Year = {1977}}

@article{HauserChomskyFitch2002,
    Author = {Hauser, Marc and Chomsky, Noam and Fitch, W. Tecumseh},
    Journal = {Science},
    Number = {5598},
    Pages = {1569--1579},
    Title = {The Faculty of Language: What Is It, Who Has It, and How Did It Evolve?},
    Volume = {298},
    Year = {2002}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-lastname}
\begin{document}
\cite{BerwickPietroskiYankama2011,Chomsky1977,HauserChomskyFitch2002}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Yes. I want to change the naming order in references.

Comment: @Mico You're absolutely right, of course. I don't know what I was thinking with the original answer. I've fixed things properly now. Thanks.

Comment: +1. Indeed, I'm always happy to upvote your postings.  :-)

Comment: Thanks. I got exactly what I wanted. I cannot fully understand the way your changed code works though—```bst``` is harder than ```tex``` for me.

Comment: @JunyongKim All I did was add a conditional which checks whether the current name being processed (represented by the `nameptr` variable) is the  is the first one or not, and then either uses the `{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}` schema (if `nameptr` > 1) or the `{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}` schema (if `nameptr` = 1).

Comment: Thank you. May I ask one more? How can I change the periods at the end of the years to commas? For example, Chomsky, Noam and Howard Lasnik (1977), Filters and control. I saw [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346144) but want the commas rather than removing the periods.

Comment: @JunyongKim The comma there seems quite odd to me, but you can use the same trick as in the linked question, but just use `,\removeperiod` instead of just `\removeperiod` in the modified `output.year.check` function.

Comment: I thought that the ```,``` in front of ```\removeperiod``` adds the commas after ```\cite``` parentheses before references—it seems ```output.year.check``` only affects anything inside references. Thank you!

Comment: @JunyongKim But this is really a bit of a hack since it requires both a `.bst` file change and extra code in the preamble. Since you're already modifying the `.bst` file, the proper way to do this is to remove the `new.block` line that is immediately after the  `output.year.check` line for each of the different entry functions (`article`, `book`, ... etc.). Then you don't need the `\removeperiod` macro at all.